# why checkbox shows checked while I had checked previous page's checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, alpine.js

I am using Alpine js with Tailwind CSS, There is an uncertain bug appearing below that is a checkbox selections issue. Actually, there are multiple selections type of questions, when I select one or more checkboxes and move to the next question then in next question's checkbox shows selected the same checkbox which I had selected in the previous question until I select once any of them after that it has shown current selection.
Here is the code snippet

Javascript:- `export const model = () => {
return {
me: this,
type: null,
sections: [],
currentSection: {},
selections: [],
currentIndex: 0,
currentStep: 'start',
userValidator: {
isValid: true,
submitUser() {

```
            this.userValidator.isValid = !Object.values(this.userValidator.user).some(
                (field) => !field.isValid
            );
            console.log('over here', this.userValidator.isValid);
            if (!this.userValidator.isValid) {
                return this.userValidator.isValid;
            }
            console.log(this.submission.user);
            this.currentStep = 'sections';                
        },
        validationCallback(field) {
            let { value, rules } = field;
            let isValid = iodine.isValid(value, rules);
            let errorMsg = isValid
                ? null
                : iodine.getErrorMessage(iodine.is(value, rules));
            return { isValid, errorMsg };
        },            
        user: {
            name: {
                rules: ["required"],
                validate(validator, submitted) {
                    let { isValid, errorMsg } = validator.validationCallback({...this, value: submitted.user.name});
                    this.isValid = isValid;
                    this.errorMsg = errorMsg;
                },
                isValid: null,
                errorMsg: null
            },
            email: {
                value: null,
                rules: ["required", "email"],
                validate(validator, submitted) {
                    let { isValid, errorMsg } = validator.validationCallback({...this, value: submitted.user.email});
                    this.isValid = isValid;
                    this.errorMsg = errorMsg;
                },
                isValid: null,
                errorMsg: null
            },
            company: {
                value: null,
                rules: ["required"],
                validate(validator, submitted) {
                    let { isValid, errorMsg } = validator.validationCallback({...this, value: submitted.user.company});
                    this.isValid = isValid;
                    this.errorMsg = errorMsg;
                },
                isValid: null,
                errorMsg: null
            },
            phone: {
                value: null,
                rules: ["required"],
                validate(validator, submitted) {
                    let { isValid, errorMsg } = validator.validationCallback({...this, value: submitted.user.phone});
                    this.isValid = isValid;
                    this.errorMsg = errorMsg;
                },
                isValid: null,
                errorMsg: null
            }

        },
    },
    submission: {
        user: {
            name: null,
            email: null,
            company: null,
            phone: null,
        },
    },
    name: '',
    async init() {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            this.type = data.type;
            this.sections = data.sections;
            this.currentSection = data.sections[0];
            this.currentIndex = 0;
            this.name = data.name;
            resolve();
        });
    },
    getValue(index) {
        return `${this.currentIndex}:${this.currentSection.level}:${index}`;
    },
    moveNext(forward) {
        console.log('current selections', this.selections);
        let direction = 1;
        let index = this.currentSection.level || 0;
        if (index === -1) {
            return;
        }
        if (!forward) {
            direction = -1;
        }
        index = index + direction;
        if (index < 0 || index === this.currentSection.levels.length) {
            return;
        }
        this.currentSection.level = index;
    }
};
```

};`

```
<div class="mt-4 mr-4 p-4  rounded-lg shadow-md bg-white">
                    <div class="px-4 bg-gradient-to-r from-gray-500 via-gray-900 to-gray-700 text-white rounded">
                        <h5 class="mb-1 text-base font-semibold text-white lg:text-xl inline-block"
                            x-text="currentSection.levels[currentSection.level || 0].name"></h5>
                        <h5 class="mb-1 text-base font-semibold text-white lg:text-xl inline-block"
                            x-text="currentSection.levels[currentSection.level || 0].subtitle"></h5>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="my-2 space-y-3">
                        <template x-for="(item, index) in currentSection.levels[currentSection.level || 0].items">
                            <li>
                                <label
                                    class="flex items-center p-2 text-base text-gray-500 bg-gray-50 rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-100 group hover:shadow">
                                    <input class="text-blue-500 w-4 h-4 mr-2 focus:ring-blue-400 focus:ring-opacity-25 border 
                        gray-300 rounded" type="checkbox" x-model="selections" :value="getValue(index)" />
                                    <span class="flex-1 ml-3" x-text="item.name"></span>
                                </label>
                            </li>
                        </template>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="text-left pt-4">
                        <a class="cursor-pointer border-2 border-pink-800 text-purple-700 bg-white px-3 py-2 w-2/4 rounded font-bold"
                            href="javascript:;;" @click="currentStep='levels';">
                            MAIN MENU
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-right">
                        <button
                            class="py-2 px-14 rounded bg-gradient-to-r  from-purple-700 to-purple-500 text-white capitalize hover:bg-purple-600 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                            @click="moveNext(false)">
                            &laquo; Previous
                        </button>
                        <button
                            class="py-2 px-14 rounded bg-gradient-to-r  from-purple-700 to-purple-500 text-white capitalize hover:bg-purple-600 focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
                            @click="moveNext(true)">
                            Next &raquo;
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

here data sample:-

```
"sections": [
    {

        "id": 1,
        "name": "Governance and leadership",
        "description": "A digital value vision and buy-in from the top management, articulation of a clear digital strategy, alignment of the leadership team’s internal and external actions to the buy-in, clarity of communication top-down about the benefits of digital transformation, well-defined roles, and responsibilities in the accomplishment of the shared goal. ",
        "icon": '/home.png',
        "levels": [{
            "name": "Level 1:",
            "subtitle": "Minimal",
            "icon": "",
            "items": [{ "name": "little buy-in from the executive for digital solutions or strategy" },
            { "name": "a website exists but there is no departmental digital strategy" },
            { "name": "digital value proposition not understood or developed" },
            { "name": "digital opportunities are not understood or defined" },
            { "name": "ad hoc digital projects initiated by internal groups and individuals" },
            { "name": "a social media presence or engagement with customers has not been permitted by the executive" }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Level 2:",
            "subtitle": "Informal & Reactive",
            "icon": '',
            "items": [{ "name": "value proposition of digital starting to be acknowledged by executive" },
            { "name": "exploring the impact of innovation and emerging technologies on the business" },
            { "name": "some one-off collaboration with other departments regarding digital service delivery" },
            { "name": "social media channels are monitored but social media is seen more as a risk than an opportunity" }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Level 3:",
            "subtitle": "Transitional",
            "icon": "",
            "items": [{ "name": "digital strategy in place" },
            { "name": "roles and responsibilities for delivering the digital strategy are clear and understood" },
            { "name": "benefits are well-defined, understood" },
            { "name": "strategic digital partnerships with other departments" },
            { "name": "focussed on audiences and their needs and emerging technologies" },
            { "name": "pro-active engagement with customers across all digital channels" },
            { "name": "the benefits of social media are understood and drive social media activity" },
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Level 4:",
            "subtitle": "Customer driven",
            "icon": "",
            "items": [{ "name": "digital strategy integrated into departmental planning process and influences overall organizational strategy and direction" },
            { "name": "benefits are well-defined, understood and drive all digital activity" },
            { "name": "KPIs and benefits to the business and customers understood, monitored and reported on " },
            { "name": "seamless customer experience across all channels - digital and non-digital" },
            { "name": "strategic collaboration with other departments, utilizing multiple channels" },
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Level 5:",
            "subtitle": "Transformed",
            "icon": "",
            "items": [{ "name": "digital strategy is embedded in, and indistinguishable from, the organizational vision and strategy" },
            { "name": "executive understands and fully embraces digital channels and leads by example" },
            { "name": "new services and products are born digital" },
            { "name": "non-digital services and products are re-engineered, joined up and re-born as digital" },
            { "name": "digital services and channels drive the organizational structure and reporting" },
            ]
        },
        ],
        started: true,
    },],
```

}

Comment: Could you also provide two sample datasets that reproduce your problem? Currently in `init()` `data` is just undefined.

Comment: @Dauros I have updated my question with data sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an unique [`key` attribute](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/for#keys) to the checkbox generating loop so Alpine.js can identify and remove old items completely. You can use the dynamic value of the specific checkbox for the key:

```
<template x-for="(item, index) in currentSection.levels[currentSection.level || 0].items" :key="getValue(index)">
```

Furthermore in the `init()` method you forgot to set `level` to 0:

```
this.currentSection.level = 0;
```